# Python Selenium Webdriver: while loop does not end

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie in Selenium webdriver. I am trying to extract google reviews. I wrote a script in Python which should load all google reviews related to a restaurant. The problem is that the `while` loop I used to scroll down page until all reviews load up does not end and I could not figure out where I made the mistake.  Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = 'https://www.google.com/search?tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:9&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=AOaemvJFjYToqQmQGGnZUovsXC1CObNK1g:1633336974491&q=10+famous+restaurants+in+Dunedin&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTsqaxrrDzAhXe4zgGHZPODcoQjGp6BAgKEGo&biw=1280&bih=557&dpr=2#lrd=0xa82eac0dc8bdbb4b:0x4fc9070ad0f2ac70,1,,,&rlfi=hd:;si:5749134142351780976,l,CiAxMCBmYW1vdXMgcmVzdGF1cmFudHMgaW4gRHVuZWRpbiJDUjEvZ2VvL3R5cGUvZXN0YWJsaXNobWVudF9wb2kvcG9wdWxhcl93aXRoX3RvdXJpc3Rz2gENCgcI5Q8QChgFEgIIFkiDlJ7y7YCAgAhaMhAAEAEQAhgCGAQiIDEwIGZhbW91cyByZXN0YXVyYW50cyBpbiBkdW5lZGluKgQIAxACkgESaXRhbGlhbl9yZXN0YXVyYW50mgEkQ2hkRFNVaE5NRzluUzBWSlEwRm5TVU56ZW5WaFVsOUJSUkFCqgEMEAEqCCIEZm9vZCgA,y,2qOYUvKQ1C8;mv:[[-45.8349553,170.6616387],[-45.9156414,170.4803685]]'
driver.get(base_url)
 
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='P5Bobd']").text
address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='T6pBCe']").text
overall_rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-score-container']//span[@class='Aq14fc']").text
total_reviews_text =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-score-container']//div//div//span//span[@class='z5jxId']").text
num_reviews = int (total_reviews_text.split()[0])
all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))

while len(all_reviews) < num_reviews:
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', all_reviews[-1])
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class$="activityIndicator"]')))
        #all_reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.gws-localreviews__google-review')
        all_reviews = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gws-localreviews__google-review')))
        len(all_reviews)
```

Any help would be appreciated to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `len(all_reviews)` dosen't change at any moment in your script, then if the condition is always true it will end into an infinite loop ‍♂️

You should increment the `len(all_reviews)` after `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', all_reviews[-1])` by doing something like this :

```
total_reviews = len(all_reviews)
while total_reviews < num_reviews:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', all_reviews[-1])
    total_reviews += 1
    ...
```